# Handler for NServiceBus.Address was not found

Tags: .net, nservicebus, windsor-3.0

I use version 3.2.0 of Castle Windsor and version 3.3.5 of NServiceBus.

I configure my bus in a console app like this :

```
    NServiceBus.Configure.With()
        .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
        .Log4Net()
        .XmlSerializer()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(true)
        .UnicastBus()
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
```

This bus will only be used by this console app to send messages to the bus hence I don't use the nservice bus host.

When going over that line of code, the app is throwing an exception stating that no handler could be found for NServiceBus.Address.  Indeed, inspecting my container, i don't see any registration made for it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added binding redirects for both Castle.Windsor and Castle.Core in your config file?

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Windsor" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Yes, that is setup as well as for NserviceBus oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0".  Thanks John

Comment: @VdesmedT this setup works for me!  I have modified one of our 3.3.5 samples to use Castle 3.2, you can d/l it from http://speedy.sh/Vh2G4/SendOnlyEndpoint.zip